# Elastic BeanStalk Application versions update automatically during specific time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk application version is updated automatically daily during specific time. Don't how it is getting triggered and source is upload. Can someone suggest how can we find why application version is updated and source is uploaded.

```
**Version label**                                                             **Source**
87f62452d3h673377a1d331502d8f8                             class-time-service-hzavks12/program-time-service-87f62452d3h673377a1d331502d8f8-jenkins-hzavk12-branch-deploy-program-time-service-100.zip
-jenkins-hzavk12-branch-deploy-program-time-service-100
```

Answer (score 0):

To investigate who/what triggers the deployments of your app daily during a specific time can have a look at:

- [event history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events.html) in **CloudTrial** for API calls related to EB.
- rules in **CloudWatch Events**, especially [scheduled expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) which cloud execute a lambda-based or CodePiepline deployments of your application.
- **Jenkins** setup. From the file name it seems the deployment zip  originates from Jenkins. Maybe Jenkins is performing the deployment on a recurring schedule.

Comment: No issue in deployment. The problem is everyday some unknown deployment is happening in EB and how it is happening not sure, So how can we check how that particular deployment is happening.

Comment: Have you checked in  [CloudTrial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events.html) Event history?

Comment: Restricted to cloudTrail. Anyway to check within EB and its running instance

Comment: @muku What about CloudWatch Events rules? Have you checked there? Maybe there is a recurring rule setup which triggers the deployment on a schedule? Or jenkins? From the filename it appears as jenkins is building the deployment package.

Comment: Checked in CloudWatch Events rules but nothing is there. Yeah, jenkins job is there but while checking without jenkins build application version is updated that's what i wanted to know how it is happening and what is causing for this to happen.